# Why do we say Minkowski space is flat when hyperbolic geometry has negative Gaussian curvature?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, curvature

I often hear that spacetime corresponds to a hyperbolic geometry. The distance metric is not Euclidean, it is hyperbolic, and Lorentz transformations correspond to hyperbolic rotations. Hyperbolic geometry has a negative Gaussian curvature. At the same time, I also hear that Minkowski is flat and has vanishing Riemann tensor. How do I reconcile these two apparently contradictory statements about Minkowski curvature ?

Comment: It has a vanishing Riemann tensor.

Comment: Minkowski does **not** have negative gaussian curvature. Where did you get this idea?

Comment: thanks for the answer. i made the "negative curvature" statement because distances in special relavity are hyperbolic distances, and lorentz transformations are hyperbolic rotations. thus, special relavity seems to correspond to hyperbolic geometry, which has negative constant curvature. i'm obviously confusing things, since that hyperbolic geometry apparently has nothing to do with the geometry of space-time (or of minkowski spacetime) itself ?

Comment: Hi marjimbel welcome to StackExchange and Physics SE in particular. I upvoted your question since it is a fair question that you made in good faith. I also did it as a welcome gift to compensate the actions of 2 "superior" members who down voted your very first question, for no particular reason. They clearly violated our code of conduct. In Italian people use to say - citing Dante's Divine Commedy - "Non ti curar di lor ma guarda e passa " (Let us not speak of them, but look, and pass)

Comment: thank you @magma :) . i'm honestly confused about this. people make statements like "the geometry of Minkowski 4-space is hyperbolic" all the time. perhaps those statements are wrong (if so i'd like to understand why). you see them all the time even in other SE questions ( ie. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497504/what-is-the-relationship-between-hyperbolic-geometry-and-einsteins-special-rela ) . i'm just trying to understand the two things

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure where you got that impression, as it's simply not right.

I'm guessing you read a 3D hyperbola embedded in 4D Minkowski space has constant negative curvature. That's true, but it doesn't mean Minkowski space itself has curvature. Similarly, you can embed a 3D sphere in a 4D Euclidean space, but that doesn't mean the Euclidean space has curvature.

Comment: thanks for the answer. i made the "negative curvature" statement because distances in special relavity are hyperbolic distances, and lorentz transformations are hyperbolic rotations. thus, special relavity seems to correspond to hyperbolic geometry, which has negative constant curvature. i'm obviously confusing things, since that hyperbolic geometry apparently has nothing to do with the geometry of space-time (or of minkowski spacetime) itself ?

Comment: @marjimbel That reasoning’s simply too vague. Just because the signature has a minus sign in it doesn’t make Minkowski space a hyperbola. For example, distances on your standard hyperbola are positive but distances in Minkowski space can be positive or negative.

Comment: you would concede that the geometry of spacetime is not euclidean though? so if it's not euclidean, then what is it ? also, i think for hyperbolic geometry distances can be negative @knzhou [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_geometry) . i've often read that spacetime corresponds to a hyperbolic geometry [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/497504/what-is-the-relationship-between-hyperbolic-geometry-and-einsteins-special-rela). i'm surprised at the reaction here. i'm just trying to reconcile the correspondence with hyperbolic geometry and minkowski being flat

Comment: @marjimbel You just have to read the equations more carefully. There are multiple things called "hyperbolic" that are quite different. The simplest true statement is that hyperbolic _space_ embeds nicely in Minkowski _spacetime_. They aren't literally exactly the same.

Comment: @marjimbel Looking at that Math.SE link you posted, it seems to be saying the exact same thing I am: the "hyperboloid model" of hyperbolic space is just an appropriately chosen subset of Minkowski spacetime. The technical details are usually obscured in popular-level presentations, where it's oversimplified to "relativity means non-Euclidean geometry, specifically hyperbolic geometry, describes reality". It's just a bit more complicated than that.

Comment: @marjimbel If the geometry is not Euclidean, then it is called non-Euclidean. The configuration space of special relativity, Minkowski space, can be described in terms of hyperbolic geometry, since the kinematic space of special relativity is hyperbolic.

Comment: See here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space#Geometry from which I quote below:

Comment: "Minkowski space is not endowed with a Euclidean geometry, and not with any of the generalized Riemannian geometries with intrinsic curvature, those exposed by the model spaces in hyperbolic geometry (negative curvature) and the geometry modeled by the sphere (positive curvature). The reason is the indefiniteness of the Minkowski metric. Minkowski space is, in particular, not a metric space and not a Riemannian manifold with a Riemannian metric. However, Minkowski space contains submanifolds endowed with a Riemannian metric yielding hyperbolic geometry. " I hope this clarifies things.

Comment: As @knzhou stated it, "the "hyperboloid model" of hyperbolic space is just an appropriately chosen subset of Minkowski spacetime."

Comment: And to be clear, the Minkowski space is not a metric space when it has the minkowski metric. Minkowski space can be a metric space, but it just wouldn't have the minkowski metric.

Comment: thanks @knzhou and steinle. bare with me. the "minkowski metric" defines a "distance" which is non-euclidean. lorentz transformations (hyperbolic rotations) are those that leave it invariant. thus, it appears that the mink metric is closely related to hyperbolic geometry. you say that the kinematic space of SR is hyperbolic, but actually corresponds to an embedded sub-space of minkowski (the spacetime on which the kinematics unfold). what do you mean ? i'm having a hard time separating minkowski spacetime from the hyperbolic geometry that results from its metric. can you elaborate ?

Comment: @marjimbel I think we're going in circles, and the confusion will disappear if you just write down some math. Edit your question to say exactly what you think in equations, not words.

Comment: @marjimbel The mistake you are making is analogous to thinking that the _Euclidean_ metric is invariant under non-hyperbolic (i.e. normal) rotations which leave spheres fixed, so therefore Euclidean space must have spherical geometry and positive curvature.

Comment: oh, that is a beautiful answer knzhou. thank you. let me digest it for a while and i'll come back if its still not clear in my mind.

Comment: @DaddyKropotkin if Minkowski space is indefinite and is not a metric space how can we say it is "flat"?

Comment: Please read my words more closely. I said "the Minkowski space is not a metric space when it has the minkowski metric." In mathematics, sometimes the Minkowski space is not endowed with the Minkowski metric. It's worth it to be precise about these things since otherwise it leads to great confusion. Not sure what it means for Minkowski space to be "indefinite" though